# How to call Apple Authorization API from PyQt4

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, sudo

I am currently working on a PyQt4 app which requires administrator privileges to access some files. I would like it to follow Apple guidelines and open the Authenticate Dialog to prompt the user to input their password in order to perform administrator tasks.

I have already looked into [MacPython Authorization package](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Authorization), but it seems a bit outdated and it only can be used to launch external processes and I am already using subprocess to do that.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170771/mac-os-x-python-gui-administrator-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X Python GUI Administrator Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170771/mac-os-x-python-gui-administrator-prompt)