# Mac OS X Python GUI Administrator Prompt

Tags: python, macos, authorization, sudo

I have an OS X Python application that uses wxPython for it's GUI controls. I'm looking to prompt the user for administrative rights (akin to using the Authorization Service API in Objective-C) before starting a network service.

The closest library I have found is Bob Ippolito's [Authorization library](http://www.undefined.org/python/#authorization) but it is fairly outdated and has compatibility issues with Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.4 / Python 2.6.4).

My workaround would be to create an Objective-C launcher that runs the python application with administrative rights but that feels fairly kludgy.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your entire script with admin privileges by making it into a native Mac OS X application using  [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

Answer (score 5):

If it's just a shell command that you need to run, requesting elevated privileges, then you can do this:

```
os.system("""osascript -e 'do shell script "<commands go here>" " with administrator privileges'""")
```

It will run a shell command within the applescript interpreter and prompt the user for their account credentials; effectively running the command using sudo.

Note that you'll have fun escaping quotes within your command, e.g.

```
os.system("""osascript -e 'do shell script "mkdir -m 0775 -p \\"%s\\" " with administrator privileges'"""%d)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do this so the user only needs to enter their password once? If I have several of these, the user needs to input their password for each time it's called

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the answer to another question posted here: [What kind of API should I use to elevate user privilege to super-user in a Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123055/what-kind-of-api-should-i-use-to-elevate-user-privilege-to-super-user-in-a-mac-os)

Comment: There aren't Python bindings that I could find, but I think I can use ctypes and launchd(8) to accomplish what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: That's also my impression. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run "*ls*" command and ask for the password

```
os.system("""
osascript -e 'do shell script "ls"  with administrator privileges'
""")
```